# Sharepoint/WSS Reporting Services Integration woes

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, reporting-services

after a number of failed attempts i seem to have successfully installed the Reporting services add-in to my WSS farm. However, I seem to be missing most of the enhanced functionality eg no report library template, no report center site template. the only additional functionality available is the report viewer web part.

background:
2 server WSS 3.0 farm with CA (Central admin) WFE (web front end) and reporting services addin installed on 1, and SQL05 SP2 with Reporting services (RS) and all databases installed on other. I have a VM environment set up and have rolled this back and repeated a number of times.

I have configured RS within CA and activated 'Report Server INtegration Feature'. Within the 'site settings' I have a 'Reporting Services' heading with a 'manage shared schedules' item/link, not sure if there should be other options?

I was of the understanding that to view reports within sharepoint i could either create a new site using the 'report center' template or add a report library to an existing site, neither of which seems available

I am at a loss as to what to do, as all online information seems to do with dealing with installation issues/errors, which i seem to have eventually got past

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is:

- create a document library (reports library is good too)
- add all reports content types to the doclib
- upload your report using the right content type
- create a new datasource object
- associate the 2 using the contextual menu of the report item

Comment: Thanks, but that is the point of my question....none of these options are available. I have a report viewer web part and 3 report content types; Report Builder Model, Report Builder Report and Report Datasource. Shouldnt I have other content types?

Comment: If you already have a report library and the content type associated to it, just follow the step I mentioned.